# How to add ForceAuthn optional SAML attribute in SAML request of service provider(slack,zoom). I use Azure active director as Identity Provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, slack, saml-2.0

Basically, I want service provider users to be force re authenticate against my identity provider (Azure Active Directory) after application logout even the idp session is already present. And I am sure that with the help of `forceauthn` parameter we can achieve this.

I tried to insert `forceauthn="true"` in idp metadata file and upload it to service provide but it won't works Could anyone please suggest me how can I mention `forceauthn` parameter in SAML request so that the things works.

Answer (score 0):

Just because an Identity Provider (Azure AD, in this case) supports a forced authentication in response to an `AuthnRequest`'s `ForceAuthn=True` statement doesn't mean that Service Providers like Slack and Zoom expose the `ForceAuthn` control to their customers' organization administrators. Neither of your example Service Providers provides it for SP-init. You'll need to submit a feature request to the respective companies. They likely already have a request to which your organization can be attached. Be sure to provide them with a business case for offering it.

That said, both of those example organizations support Identity Provider-initiated SAML as well, which would allow you to completely control the entire authentication experience (with only minor losses of authentication functionality).

Some things I might ask if I find myself in the same position as you:

- Why don't I trust the user's current session?
- How does doing multiple authentications affect my users' "single sign-on" experience?
- Will my approach lead to further password fatigue and push users to choose easier passwords?